# SourceKitServiceがクラッシュしないようにしたい

Tags: xcode, swift

SourceKitServiceがクラッシュして困っています。直ったと思ってもすぐにまたクラッシュします。

クラッシュしないようにする方法はありますか？

Comment: それでも彼女はついてきてくれてるんです。大事にしてあげてください。iOS シミュレータで、`Hardware>Device>Manage Devices`から `Remove all devices` を選ぶんだり、`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` や、`~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode` を削除するとまだやり直せるかもしれません。あなたの行動が求められています。 (参考: http://blog.landfront.info/archives/335 )

Comment: 内容がはっきりしない書き方だったため、一旦はクローズしましたが、質問されている本質的な問題は有用なものであると考え、誰にでも伝わりやすいよう編集させていただきました。

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto 質問のスタイルを私の方で書き換えてしまったので、上のコメントは回答として投稿していただいた方がよいかもしれません。

Comment: たしかこれは、ノリが良い質問だったので・・・後ほど整理します。

Answer (score 5):

念のためですが、Xcode 6.1.1 はお使いでしょうか？：

6.1.1 の修正点として、「SourceKit クラッシュのよくある原因を多数修正した」と挙げられています：
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-DontLinkElementID_10

個人的には 6.1.1 に限らず最近のバージョンで改善しているように感じているのですが、masakih さんのところでトラブルが続いているようでしたら、それは Apple にしか修正することはできないので、地道にバグレポートを送ってあげるしかないかな、と思います：
http://devforums.apple.com/